# How to do Error Handeling in Angular (Sweetalert2)

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript

Here is the code where I use delete confirmation I want to add Error Handeling if it not delete the data then I can handel the error

```
confirmPopUp(){
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Are You Sure?',
    text: 'Deleting Service Team Detail',
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText:('Yes, delete it'),
    cancelButtonText: 'No, Keep it'
    
  }).then((result) => {
    
    if(result.value){
        this.deleteServiceTeamById(40);
      Swal.fire(
        'Deleted!',
        'Your imaginary File has been Deleted',
        'success'
      )
    } else if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel){
      
    }
  })
}
```

I want to add the solution similiar like that but Unable to understand how to add this in my code

Example:

```
that.http.get(url, {"headers": headers})
        .map(res => res)
        .subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data);
          if (data.status === 200) {
            resolve();
          } else {
            reject(data.status);
          }
      })          
    })
```

Comment: Hello @Mohit Singh, i can see you used "resolve()" and "reject()" , so are you using promises to handle this http request?

Comment: hi mohit, can you explain it further what are you doing ?

Comment: Hey Actually It's a List Where I Have Few Options Like View, Edit & Delete I use Sweetalert2 for Confirmation Popup but It's Not Really working Properly If I do yes It shows that the Details Are deleted but It's Not working and I also have to give the 'Id' manually unable to do it Automatically I want this Functionality in working

Answer (score 0):

Both are Async tasks, means they should **wait** for the task to execute any code after that,

there are several ways to handle this, but one of the easiest i can suggest is this one (with modifications i made):
Important: i will make this suggestion basing on the given chunks of code, this does not mean this is the only solution.

Http request logic (basing on promises):

```ts
/**
 * the Http delete request to the API
 *
 */
deleteHttpRequest(url, headers){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        this.http.get(url, {"headers": headers})
                    .map(res => res) // .map in this case has no sense you can remove it
                    .subscribe(
                       data => {
                         console.log(data);
                         if (data.status === 200) {
                           resolve();
                         } else {
                           reject(data.status);
                         }
                        },
                         serverError => {
                           reject(serverError.error); // basing on HttpResponseError
                         }
                        );          
                });
     }

}
```

Confirm popup

```ts
/**
 * Confirm before delete
 */
confirmPopUp(confirmCallBack, cancelCallback){
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Are You Sure?',
    text: 'Deleting Service Team Detail',
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText:('Yes, delete it'),
    cancelButtonText: 'No, Keep it'
    
  }).then((result) => {    
    if(result.value){
       confirmCallBack();  // <======= Here we will execute Http request      
    } else if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel){
       cancelCallback();  // <======== Here you can do whatever you want after canceling your delete action.
    }
  })
}
```

Put all in one:

```ts
/**
 * Call popup confirmation then execute logic basing on confirmation status (confirm : execute http Request,  cancel: do whatever you want)
 */
executeHttpAndGetResult() {
  this.confirmPopUp(
    () => {     // when confirmed we will call deleteHttpRequest (confirmCallBack)
    this.deleteHttpRequest(url, headers)
        .then(
          res => { // when delete successed  
            Swal.fire('Deleted!','Your imaginary File has been Deleted', 'success');
        .catch( // catch will be called whenever data.status !== 200 or there is a server Error returned.
          error => {
         // display an error popup or whatever
          }
        );
    },
    // when confirmation was canceled what we will do (cancelCallback)
    () => {
     // @todo
     } 
  );
}
```